# how to write a WHILE loop in Rythm

Tags: java, template-engine, templating, rythm

I try to write a While loop in Rythm within HTML tags but I can't

something like this code:

```
@{
int i = 0;
while( i< 5){
i++;
}

<h2>hello</h2>

@{
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment **Rythm** does not support `while` loop. Use `for` loop instead for your case:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    <h2>hello</h2>
}
```